# How to bulkify the Case Closed Milestones of an Entitlement processes?

Tags: apex, trigger, casemilestone, entitlements

I have the following conditions which closed the milestones based on the Status=Closed, Assume I have the 3 milestones which I wants to closed. If 100 agents starts working on it simultaneous, then it look to me that it wont worked. The steps no. 18, 20 and 22 will give SOQL 101 error

Could you please help me to bulkify the below code ?

```
String mileStoneName;
if(cs.SubCategory__c == 'Auth'){

                        if(cs.Status == XXXX && (cs.SubStatus__c == XXXX || cs.SubStatus__c == XXXX)){
                            caseIds.add(cs.Id);
                            if(cs.isAuthRequest == 'Yes'){
                                mileStoneName = 'Milestone1';
                            }else{
                                mileStoneName = 'Milestone2';
                            }
                        }
                        else if(cs.Status == YYYY && cs.SubStatus__c == MMMM){
                            caseIds.add(cs.Id);
                            mileStoneName = 'Milestone3';
                        }
                        else if(cs.Status == 'Closed'){
                            caseIds.add(cs.Id);
                            MilestoneUtils.completeMilestone(caseIds, 'Milestone3', System.now()); // line-18
                            if(cs.isAuthRequest == 'Yes'){
                                MilestoneUtils.completeMilestone(caseIds, 'Milestone1', System.now()); // line-20
                            }else{
                                MilestoneUtils.completeMilestone(caseIds, 'Milestone2', System.now()); // line-22
                            }
                        }
                    }

if(!caseIds.isEmpty() && !String.isEmpty(milestoneName)){
    MilestoneUtils.completeMilestone(caseIds, milestoneName, System.now());
}
```

The below code to complete the milestones

```
public static void completeMilestone(Set<Id> caseIds, String milestoneName, DateTime complDate){
        List<CaseMilestone> cmsToUpdate = [SELECT Id,completionDate 
                                            FROM CaseMilestone
                                            WHERE caseId in :caseIds 
                                            AND MilestoneType.Name = :milestoneName 
                                            AND completionDate = NULL LIMIT 1];
        System.debug('Case Milestone :: '+cmsToUpdate.size()+', Case Milestone Id :: '+cmsToUpdate);

        if(cmsToUpdate.isEmpty() == false){
            for (CaseMilestone cm : cmsToUpdate){
                cm.completionDate = complDate;
            }
            update cmsToUpdate;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Right, Milestone.Complete is common method written to complete the milestone. Please see updated code above. Also please post code based on my above code ?

Comment: If above given is your entire  code, and your code have only one SOQL query than How Exception of SOQL 101 can occur? I believe this is not your entire code and still you need to manage your code according to Governor Limits

Comment: No, I have almost 70 such if else conditions. Please guide now

Comment: @user4567570, you are calling `MilestoneUtils.completeMilestone` in a loop, which must be avoided. Can you post your updated code, specially how it is looping. How you are getting `cs` value in the logic

Comment: @SantanuBoral - You're right. I just corrected that logic now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have corrected logic using below code. I hope its out of the for loop now :)

```
List<String> mileStoneList = ................. // get the list of active milestones on the case
String mileStoneName;
String isClosed = false;

for(Case c : cases){
    .................
    ..................
    if(cs.SubCategory__c == 'Auth'){

        if(cs.Status == XXXX && (cs.SubStatus__c == XXXX || cs.SubStatus__c == XXXX)){
            caseIds.add(cs.Id);
            if(cs.isAuthRequest == 'Yes'){
                mileStoneName = 'Milestone1';
            }else{
                mileStoneName = 'Milestone2';
            }
        }
        else if(cs.Status == YYYY && cs.SubStatus__c == MMMM){
            caseIds.add(cs.Id);
            mileStoneName = 'Milestone3';
        }
        else if(cs.Status == 'Closed'){
            caseIds.add(cs.Id);
            isClosed = true;  // closed all mileStones
        }
    }

    if(!String.isEmpty(milestoneName)){
        MilestoneUtils.completeMilestone(caseIds, milestoneName, System.now());
    }

    if(isClosed){
        MilestoneUtils.completeAllMilestone(caseIds, milestoneName, System.now());
        isClosed = false;
    }
}
```